About the iterator protocol in C++
The GoF book Design Patterns suggests that  begin() and end() should be iterator methods. In C++, the iterator protocol specifies that the begin() and end() must be methods of the iterable object.

why is it implemented this way? So that you can easily write something like std::find(a.begin() +3, a.begin() + 4, 5)?
If iterators in C++ were implemented as described in the GoF book, then these would actually be ranges?


(2) Yes. (1) Arguably this is a minor design mistake. Rust has a single .iter() method, I think?

I wouldn't even call it a mistake. You only have so many options when the intent is to make raw pointers model iterators as well.

(1) So that std::find can be written this way: template <typename IT, typename T> IT find(IT first, IT last, T const& value);. (2) No, iterators are not ranges — but a pair of iterators can be (and often are) used as a range.  Ranges were added in C++20 (but I prefer Niebler's ranges-v3 library, since it has more stuff, and I'm stuck in C++17).

In 2), what does "these" refer to?

That book is geared very much towards "object-obsessive" languages, like Java and Smalltalk. Some of it barely makes sense in other contexts.

The initial assumption is already wrong. The C++ protocol is std::begin(iterableObject) and std::end(iterableObject), which (unless overloaded or specialized) forward to iterableObject.begin() and iterableObject.end(). One important overload is the standard overload for arrays, with the obvious meaning.
The reason for this is that the original STL (before the C++ 1998 standard) was already designed to use raw arrays, which can't provide begin and end methods. Instead, the iterators for raw arrays are raw pointers. (e.g. int a[4] and int*). Your example std::find will work out of the box with them, e.g. `std::find(a, a+4, 5)

GoF doesn't assume C++, but instead assumes "pure OO" languages. There's no free function in pure OO languages, so no begin(iterable)
